# Can LightDM greeter blank the screen to save power on laptop?

Tags: xfce, gnu-screen, lightdm, light-locker

LightDM would display the greeter (login box) after Lock Screen was activated. The display with the greeter would stay on and I suspect that would chew up battery (I'm using a laptop). Is there any option to get the greeter to go blank after a short while, then a key press would turn back on the login box?

I'm running Xfce 4.16 on Mint 20.2.

Answer (score 0):

LightDM and other display managers do not do any power management.

You must change X.org parameters instead as described here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Display_Power_Management_Signaling